# Split Excel VBA window vertically

Tags: excel, vba

Horizonal splitting is simple.
[image]

Is it possible to split vertically? Have wide screen so right hand side is empty anyways.

Edit: I would want to see basically a view of the **SAME** module on the left, and on the right side of the screen. I know I can put multiple windows next to each other about **different** modules.
A workaround could be to split the code into multiple modules and change variable scope, but I hope there is a simpler way.

Comment: Appears when a new window is inserted.

Comment: @Dy.Lee Thanks for reply! Do you know whether it's possible to see the SAME module splitted vertically? See edit

Comment: It doesn't seem to be vertical division in one module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think the only workaround is to:

1. insert an additional module
2. copy over your code there
3. arrange these 2 modules vertically, and use e.g. the right-hand side only for viewing, while modifying the left-hand one, to stay consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Appears when a new window is inserted.

[image]

Comment: this is horizontal